# How do I disable the security dialog alert?

Tags: windows-10, security, internet-explorer, download

I did turn off downloads on IE and would like to to turn off this secutity alert. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: This notification/alter is caused by you disabling downloads. If you want to get rid of it, then enable File Download, and restart IE.

Comment: If what you want is downloads disabled **and** to not have this warning, i.e. you want no warning that downloads are disabled, then you need to be clear that this is your goal.

Comment: @Mokubai: Yes, this is my goal. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 2):

By disabling downloads in Internet Explorer you have caused this message to appear.

Re-enable downloads in the same place you disabled them and this message should go away.

Comment: I'm sorry if the question wasn't clear, I want to turn off downloads and this dialog box on IE. I edited the question.

Comment: @Jack What your trying to achieve cannot be done, you cannot disable file downloading without enabling that notification.  The only way to get rid of the alert is to enable file downloading